# Range in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please help me understand the below code.

```
Set items = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
```

What I dont understand is how the range is set up? Which area is covered by `A2:A` and `A1` according to this? I know if I have a table like below this code works

[image]

But if I change the table location to following how do I change the example code?
[image]

Comment: The result of `items` is not `A2:A`, it's `A2:A4`, as `4` from `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`. So for your second screenshot, it should be `"C5:C" & Range("C4").End(xlDown).Row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code is separated into parts and in message boxes you will be able to see what happens, HTH.

```
Sub test()

    ' Range.End Property:
    ' Returns a Range object that represents the cell at the end of the region that contains the source range.
    ' Equivalent to pressing END+DOWN ARROW.
    Dim endXlDown As Range
    Set endXlDown = Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    MsgBox "endXlDown.Address = " & endXlDown.Address

    Dim endXlDownRow As Long
    endXlDownRow = endXlDown.Row
    MsgBox "endXlDown.Row = " & endXlDown.Row

    Dim targetAddress As String
    targetAddress = "A2:A" & endXlDownRow
    MsgBox "targetAddress = " & targetAddress

    Dim items As Range
    Set items = Range(targetAddress)
    MsgBox "items.Address = " & items.Address

    items.Select ' and here you see the resulting range as selection
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> Which area is covered by `A2:A` and `A1` according to this?

The code is not trying to cover `A2:A` nor `A1`.

In this code:

```
Set items = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
```

The part `"A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` is combined as **one** parameter of [`Range()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff847104%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

- `A2:A` is a [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251467%28v=office.14%29.aspx);
- `&` is a [`String` concatenation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264104%28v=office.14%29.aspx);
- `Range("A1")` selects `A1`;
- `Range("A1").End(xlDown)` [selects down to the last "region" cell in `A`, starting from `A1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839539%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (in this case, `A4`);
- `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` returns the [selected cell's row number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196952%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (in this case, 4);

So the whole part ends up as `"A2:A" & "4"`, or `A2:A4`.

Given this, for your second screenshot, you can go with a similar process:

1. `C5:C` selects from `C5` (which is the first "data" cell of column "Item");
2. `&` concatenates string;
3. `Range("C4")` selects `C4` (which is the "title" cell of column "Item");
4. `Range("C4").End(xlDown)` selects down to the last non-empty cell in `C` start from `C4`;
5. `Range("C4").End(xlDown).Row` returns the selected cell's row number (in this case, 7);

So for your second screenshot, you got:

```
Set items = Range("C5:C" & Range("C4").End(xlDown).Row)
```